# Is it possible to add Network interceptors to encrypt and decrypt data payload in retrofit library

Tags: android, encryption, retrofit2

My application communicate with server over https, but to provide additional security, i am told to encrypt the data payload since it contains sensitive data. And as there are lot of web service methods, i am looking for a solution where i can encrypt the request and decrypt the response at a common place, instead of performing encryption/decryption at all classes i use and save lots of coding.

After some research, i found that network interceptors can be used to rewrite request/response.

Is it a good practice? If not,please explain

Can you show some examples to rewrite request/response body.

Comment: Yes it is a good practice, that's why it's a core part of the library, Just think of it as a way to override the whole request

Comment: as for examples, it would entirely depend on a more concise concept of what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes, It's good to secure your request and response. And yes we can do using Interceptors of okhttpclient. And there are many encryption/decryption algorithms for that like GCM and many more.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static final Interceptor PARAMS_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();
        if (original.body() instanceof FormBody) {
            TempFormBodyBuilder.Builder newFormBody = new TempFormBodyBuilder.Builder();
            FormBody oldFormBody = (FormBody) original.body();
            for (int i = 0; i < oldFormBody.size(); i++) {
                final String encodedName = oldFormBody.encodedName(i);
                String encodedValue = oldFormBody.encodedValue(i);
                if (encodedName.equals("info")) {
                    final String dInfo = URLDecoder.decode(encodedValue, "UTF-8");
                    LogUtil.i(TAG, "info need to be encode : " + dInfo);
                    encodedValue = encodeInfo(dInfo);
                    newFormBody.addEncoded(encodedName, encodedValue);
                } else {
                    newFormBody.addAlEncoded(encodedName, encodedValue);
                }
            }
            final TempFormBodyBuilder builder = newFormBody.build();
            requestBuilder.method(original.method(), builder);
            requestBuilder.header("Content-Length", builder.contentLength() + "");
            final Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            Buffer requestBuffer = new Buffer();
            if (request.body() != null) {
                request.body().writeTo(requestBuffer);
            }
            LogUtil.i(TAG, request.url() + (request.body() != null ? "?" + _parseParams(request.body(), requestBuffer) : ""));
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }
};

private final Interceptor DECODE_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        String type = chain.request().header("TYPE");
        String encryption = chain.request().header("encryption");
        Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .headers(chain.request()
                        .headers()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .removeAll("encryption")
                        .build())
                .build();
        if (encryption) {
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);
            ResponseBody body = originalResponse.body();
            String result = body.string();
            try {
                result = DES.decode(result, key);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogUtil.log(e);
                RxBus.getInstance().postEvent(new AuthException(e, AuthException.MORE_PHONES_LOGIN_CODE));
                throw new AuthException(e, AuthException.MORE_PHONES_LOGIN_CODE);
            }
            return originalResponse.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), result))
                    .build();
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }
};

    private Manager(Cache cache) {
    final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
            retryOnConnectionFailure(true).
            addNetworkInterceptor(PARAMS_INTERCEPTOR).
            addInterceptor(DECODE_INTERCEPTOR).
            addInterceptor(LOGGING_INTERCEPTOR).
            connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
            readTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
            writeTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (cache != null) {
        builder.cache(cache);
    }
    this.mOkHttpClient = builder.build();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do it as per Jesse Wilson explanation regarding intercepter you can customize request payload using intercepter

https://publicobject.com/2014/12/31/okhttp-2-2-has-interceptors/

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class that implements `Interceptor`

```
 class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        // Get reuqest info
        Request initialReq = chain.request();
        // Create modified request to return
        Request modRequest = initialReq;
        Response response = chain.proceed(modRequest);
        // your logic...

        return response;
    }
}
```

Then add it to your `OkHttpClient` like this:

```
TokenInterceptor tokenInterceptor = new TokenInterceptor();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
            .build();
```

You already are receiving a response somewhere when you do this (below is only one way of calling the service, it may vary):

```
Call<T> call = service.yourMethod();
call.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response){

        // decryption logic
}
```

Where `T` is the class where you model your response.

Comment: thanks. the above code shows how to intercept the request. can you add code to intercept the response body as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by intercept the reponse body, if you already implemented Retrofit, you already are getting the reponse somewhere, there's no need for "interception", you can decrypt it as soon as received

Comment: As you showed code to rewrite the request by using the interceptor, the same way i want to decrypt the response at a common place instead of writing code in each classes to decode it.

Comment: That would depend entirely on your architecture, but check updated answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this, below sample shows adding header and other data to common **API** calls you can encrypt and decrypt here

```
public RetroInterface getService() {

    //add intercept here first

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

        //this call back method returns each network request here
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();
            Request.Builder requestBuilder;
            if (userToken != null) {
                // Request customization: add request headers
                requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store")
                        .addHeader("channel", "mobile")
                        .addHeader(WebConstants.X_TOKEN, userToken);
            } else {
                //adding temporary token 
                requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store")
                        .addHeader("channel", "mobile");
            }
            return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
        }


    });


    //build the request here with the intercepted requests from above
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
            baseUrl(WebConstants.BASE_DOMAIN).
            build();
    Log.d(APIService.class.getCanonicalName(), "token : " + userToken);
    return retrofit.create(RetroInterface.class);
}
```